# change menu direction left to right?

Tags: android

i want to change the menu direction so app icon and title displays on right (default is left).

already add `android:supportsRtl="true"`to AndroidManifest.xml

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check out this library 
https://github.com/semsamot/ActionBarRTLizer

Comment: took me 5 hour to make it with this library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
android:layout_gravity="right"